# What is the proper way to request team/project change?

Tags: management, negotiation, team, project-management, projects

I am working in a software firm on a project which doesn't have any work left. The team is of only 3 people, all three of us are from a different domain. Even If I ask for the project change, I don't think management will approve it due to a lack of backup in the team.

What is the proper way to ask for team change?

Should I start searching for a new job, hold one offer for backup, resign and in negotiations ask for the change?

I am fairly new in the industry I don't have any idea how these things work?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There are only 3 people handling the project. Each one of us is from a different domain.

Comment: I wouldn't make mere assumptions without facts - why not make an appointment with your mgmt and explain your situation? In case they are refusing your request you can still play the 'resigning'-card.. btw, you could clarify to mgmt that you still willing to maintain the project when there's a demand for it.

Comment: Did you join this firm with the understanding that your current project would be the only one?

Comment: I'm confused. If there's no work left, why would managers want to keep *anybody* on the project?

Comment: @dwizum for maintenance, which is also not very much.

Comment: @sf02 There was no such discussion. I have been working on the same project from the last 18 months.

Answer (score 3):

I am making some assumptions here, but

- make an appointment with your manager, as already stated in the comments, and prepare well for it. If I understand you correctly, it should be fairly easy to generate some numbers that will show that there's not much work in the project. Be it numbers of ticket, hours worked on tasks or else (I don't know your industry).
- it's also good to point our your reason that you want to leave the project: self-development in the field you're working, the urge to actually "do" something in your working time etc.
- if you think the mgmt won't let you change projects completely, suggest a part-time solution: you can keep working in the old project like 50% of your time, get into a new project the rest of the time, and if you did the numbers beforehand mgmt will see that the old project is still running and maybe you need even less time there than expected. This means you could reduce the time spent for this old project even more in the future
- as a side note, talk to your other team members. Do they back your plans? Then this is also a valid point to make when speaking to mgmt
- if there's absolutely no possibility that you change the project, I think you should leave. Props are that you won't work with this company forever anyway, and you need to develop your knowledge and capabilities to be interesting for a new employer. In my opinion, staying in this project won't do this.